# In apache, subdomain http://subdomain.domain working but www.subdomain.domain not working

Tags: apache-2.2, domain, subdomain

I have configured a subdomain in my Apache2 httpd server, but having a problem. I can reach the subdomain by using `http://subdomain.domain.com` but do not access it by using `www.subdomain.domain.com`

My top-level domain say, domain.com can be reached with both `http://domain.com` and `www.domain.com`

Here is source from my subdomain config file in sites-available

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName subdomain.domain.com
    ServerAlias www.submdomain.domain.com
    ServerAlias http://www.subdomain.domain.com

    ServerAdmin admin@domain

    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain/subdomain
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/domain/subdomain>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
```

Where is the problem? Here in this configuration or in A records of my domain name?

**EDIT** : I get this message from my ISP when I try to reach by `www.subdomain.domain.com` = "Sorry, the website you were looking for is unavailable."

And when I used a proxy to reach it, it shows this error message = "The requested resource could not be loaded. libcurl returned the error: Couldn't resolve host 'www.subdomain.domain.com"

Comment: What happens or error message do you get when you try to access www.subdomain.domain.com ?

Comment: @Iain: I cannot reach there, my ISP shows this message "Sorry, the website you were looking for is unavailable."

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to provide more details, ie. what error is returned when you try to reach your www.subdomain.domain.com.
My guess is you don't have www.subdomain.domain.com in your DNS server.

Comment: I have edited my question to include error message, have a look now

Comment: Can you paste the apache2 error report.

Answer (score 0):

> Couldn't resolve host 'www.subdomain.domain.com"

You need to configure your DNS to resolve `www.subdomain.domain.com` to your server's IP address.

Comment: I am not using DNS, I am using A records and I have added subdomain to it.

Comment: @Abhi: You are using DNS what do you think an [A record](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_DNS_record_types) is ?

Comment: I figured it out, I had to configure cname for it to work with www as well.

Comment: So, like I said you had to configure your DNS ...